# Do subset sigma algebras exist in general?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a set and $M$ be a sigma algebra of $X$. If $U \subset X$, is it true that the set $M_U = \{E \cap U|E \in M\}$ is a sigma algebra? I'm getting the countable union part, but not compliments:

$$(E\cap U)^C = E^C \cup U^C$$

I'm not sure what to do with $U^C$

Comment: You need the complement relative to $U$, which is $U \setminus E$. $M_U$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $U$, not on $X$.

Comment: "..and $M$ be *it's* sigma algebra.." A set $X$ does not have a (canonical) $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: ^ ya, sorry, fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you want to show that $\mathcal{M}_U$ is an $U$  $\sigma-$ algebra, thus you have to show that $$U \cap (E \cap U)^c \in \mathcal{M}_U$$
But $$U \cap (E \cap U)^c = U \cap (E^c \cup U^c) = U \cap E^c \in \mathcal{M}_U$$

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is a set, $\mathcal M$ a $\sigma$-algebra on it and $f:Y\to X$ is a function then the collection $f^{-1}(\mathcal M)$ can be shown to be a $\sigma$-algebra on $Y$.

Observe that in that situation $f^{-1}(E^{\complement})=f^{-1}(E)^{\complement}$.

You can apply that here by taking $Y=U$ and $f:U\to X$ the inclusion.

That will lead to $f^{-1}(\mathcal M)=\mathcal M_U$ here.

The complement of $E\subseteq U$ in universe $U$ is $E^{\complement}\cap U$.

This because you are focusing on a collection of subsets of $U$.